# Relative Placement of \psplot to \psaxes in pstricks

Tags: pstricks, plot

## What I have done

I placed a `\psframe` in a `pspicture`-environment and also some `\psaxes` and a `\psplot`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add, pst-plot}
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(10,20)

\psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=white](10,20)

\psaxes(2,2)(1,1)(4,4)
\psplot{0}{4}{x}

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

## What I would like

At the moment the plot uses the point `(0,0)` as its origin, which is the bottom-left coordinate of the `pspicture`-environment and the frame. I would like `\psplot` to use `(2,2)` from `\psaxes` as its origin for plotting. That means that if for some reason I move around the `\psaxes` in the frame (e.g. to make room for other objects) or the `\psplot`-function grows somewhat more complex, I don´t have to worry moving the plot around, as it always revolves around `(2,2)`.

If the function goes like this, for example: `\psplot{0}{4}{x exp 2}`, I would not have to do anything, as the `{0}{4}` would be relative to `(2,2)` from `\psaxes`. Is this doable or for some other reason very dumb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the plots with `\rput`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add, pst-plot}
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(10,20)

\psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=white](10,20)

\psaxes(2,2)(1,1)(4,4)
\psplot{0}{2.5}{x mul x}

\psset{linecolor=blue}
\rput(2,2){\psplot{0}{2.5}{x mul x}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is easy with the `origini={abscissa,ordinate}`key (note the use of braces, not parentheses). Also, the `algebraic` option lets you enter with the usual notation, not R.P.N.:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{scrbook}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(10,20)

\psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=white](10,20)

\psaxes(2,2)(1,1)(4,4)
\psset{origin = {2,2}, algebraic}
\psplot{0}{4}{x}
\psplot[linecolor = IndianRed]{0}{4}{x^2}

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]